# Emplear try/except si se produce error de no encontrar cámara

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con mi webcam y `opencv`. Para ejecutar la cámara se emplea  la siguiente línea:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Donde el valor numérico por defecto dentro del paréntesis suele ser 0 pero también podemos poner un 1.

Este valor tiene cómo objetivo definir que cámara vas a usar, la 0 normalmente es la propia del ordenador y la 1 una externa que tengas conectada.

Hasta aquí no hay problema, el problema viene a que me plantee en que en el caso que haya una externa conectada quiero usar la externa pero si no lo hay, que el programa se de cuenta y use la cámara interna (siempre asumiendo que habrá al menos una cámara en el ordenador), entonces me plantee emplear `try` `except`.

```
try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
except:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Pero esto cuando no hay externa no funciona, es decir, nunca entra en el `except` y por lo tanto me salta un error de que no hay cámara externa. ¿Cómo debo gestionarlo si no es así?

El error es:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: Podrías pegar el error que te genera?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh hecho! Básicamente se puede resumir en, no encuentro la cámara que me defines jajaj

Comment: El problema es que esto no te genera una excepción en Python, solo un mensaje de error (`VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 1`). Si añades un `print()` después de `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`, verás que igual se ejecuta. Debes hacer la verifiaciốn de la existencia de la cámara antes de ejecutar `cv2.VideoCapture()`, en ente momento no sé cómo hacerlo, pero si lo hallo, lo publicaré como respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando como referencia [este post de SO en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049886/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-camera-is-available), lo que sucede es que se crea un objeto VideoCapture, pero inválido.

Una posible solución es:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if !cap.isOpen():
    print("Invalid device id 1, Selecting default device id 0")
    cap = cv2.videoCapture(0)
```